# Ionic 2 DatePicker Customize

Tags: datepicker, ionic2, hybrid

Is it possible to customize standard ionic 2 datepicker to display day also, meaning when user selects date, month , year, it would be nice to see what day they are choosing.

Reference:
http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-fixing-date-inputs-for-the-mobile-web/

Comment: You can already select Day Month Year with ionic 2,  what is your question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand exactly your question, but you can display more than 3 elements in a Ionic DateTime. This is just as easy as modify the pickerFormat component parameter. For example this code shows four elements to pick: hours, days, months and year.

```
<ion-datetime
     pickerFormat="mm DD MMM YYYY"
     ...
>
</ion-datetime>
```

In the following link you will see all possible formats an options to set into the pickerFormat Input.

[DateTime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the short name of day in the datepicker you should use:

```
 <ion-datetime
     pickerFormat="mm DDD MMM YYYY"
     ...
>
</ion-datetime>
```